# How to pass a file (PDF, DOC, etc) from Client (react) to server (Node - Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file, express

### Client side

I use input file to get the PDF:

```html
<html>
<body>
<input type="file" id="file_attachments" name="files" onChange=updateAttachments() multiple>
</input>
<script>
function updateAttachments() {
  let files = document.getElementById("file_attachments").files;
  console.log('attached', files);  
}
</script>
</body>
```

As you can see from the above, I use `.files`.

I successfully update my react states with the files:

```
this.setState({
   attachments: [...files]
});
```

---

### Server side

I pass the files (attachments) to my server (node) via a fetch request (POST):

```
onSend = () => {
   const url = config.API_ENDPOINT + "/api/email/send";

   const email = {
            to: this.state.emails,
            subject: this.state.subject,
            message: this.state.content,
            attachments: this.state.attachments
   };

   fetch(url, {
            method:"POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(email),
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/pdf",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
   }})
   .then(res => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                res.json().then(error => {
                    throw error
                })
            }
            return res.json()
   })
   .then(data => {
            console.log('sent complete');
            console.log(data);
   })
   .catch(err => {
            this.setState({
                error: err.message
            })
   })
}
```

However, on the server side, I receive all the data, except attachments is empty:

```
emailRouter
.route('/send')
.post(jsonParser, (req, res, next) => {
    
    console.log(req.body); //display what was received 

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'myEmail@gmail.com', // generated ethereal user
            pass: 'xxxxxx', // generated ethereal password
          },
    });


    
    transporter.sendMail({
        from: 'myEmail@gmail.com',
        to: 'All of my Subscribers <myEmail@gmail.com>',
        bcc: req.body.to,
        subject: req.body.subject,
        html: req.body.message,
        attachments: req.body.attachments,
    }, (err, info) => {
        console.log('email sent or was there an error?');
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Email Sent: ', info.response);
        }
    });
});
```

First, I'm aware that `attachments: req.body.attachments` wouldn't work for Nodemailer, I'll cross that bridge when I get there lol.
All the data received except for `req.body.attachments`?

This is what is logged by the console:

```
{
  to: [email1@gmail.com, email2@yahoo.com, anotherOne@outlook.com],
  subject: 'Test email',
  message: '<p>This email was received from Nodemailer</p>\n',
  attachments: {}
}
```

### My question is this:

1. Why am I not receiving any file data when I clearly passed it through?
2. **How do I properly pass a file from the front end to the server? If there is a better way please enlighten me. I've seen a lot of different techniques, but none have made complete sense to me yet.**

Comment: They're not under `req.files`?

Comment: Please find the below resource to get idea on how to handle file uploads in react and node https://medium.com/@minatibiswal/how-to-upload-files-in-react-with-nodejs-express-3a3dafc1b285

Comment: No, they're not in req.files or req.file on the server, I checked both.

Answer (score 1):

To pass a file from the front end to the server Please use FormData (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) from client side. And server side I would recommend you to use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload package to handle incoming files

And dont forget to set your `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Cool, I'll check this out and if it works I'll give you best answer